MSIX Silently install root certificate
I need to install certificates on the target machine which installed from MS store. Is there any way to do this?
I tried to run another application (*.exe file in my app package) as administrator to install those certificates but it not work. Application in app package cannot excute another application in the same package ( I guest so ).
